# slow data download - fetch in map

Tags: reactjs, promise, async-await, fetch

I wrote a function to download data but it works very slowly, I think.
It should download a list of people and collect income for each person.

> 1. **Is something wrong here?**
> 2. Is the fetch function a good place to sort data?

### Data:

> `people [{id, name, surname} x 400]`
> `incomes [{id,[{ value, date} x 60]]`

```
  const url = "https://example.com/";
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const useMountEffect = fun => useEffect(fun, []);

  function sum(arr) {
    let sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b.value * 1, 0).toFixed(2);
    return sum;
  }

  async function fetchData() {
    let data = [];
    try {
      data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
      await Promise.all(
        data.map(async item => {
          const res = await (await fetch(`${url+item.id}`)).json();
          item.income = sum(res.incomes);
          item.incomes = res.incomes;
          return item;
        })
      );
      data.sort((a, b) => b.income * 1 - a.income * 1);
      setPeoples(data);
    } catch (err) {
      setErrors(err);
    }
  }

  useMountEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then(setLoading(false));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are simply not using what `Promise.all` is returning to you (it doesnt mutate the data you feed to it).

The same thing happens for the `sort` function, it doesnt modify the data you feed to it, it simply returns a new array:

```
let people = await Promise.all(/* the promises */)
people = poeple.sort((a, b) => b.income * 1 - a.income * 1);
setPeoples(people);
```

The performance cost is likely due to you doing a request for each person.
While this would works for a few items, 400 would be too much.
Try sending the data of everyone from your backend, maybe on a route like the following :

```
const url = "https://example.com/people";
```

And then have them accessible individually if necessary (for other pages though)

```
const url = "https://example.com/people/:id";
```

Comment: I corrected it, but the download time still is about 5 seconds. Is that ok?

Comment: This seems like a lot, are you sure the problem is coming from your front-end and not your back-end ?

But this might be due to you making a request for each 400 ppl separatly.
If you can, you may have better performances by sending the data of all poeple with a single request form your backend by sending an array

Comment: Unfortunately I need all this data on the main page. Initially, I tried to get this data using .then() without promise.all. It worked much faster, but some of the records were missing.